# Send mail from PL/SQL - How to pass variable to UTL_MAIL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am able to find several ways to send mail from PL/SQL. 
I choose UTL_MAIL as it looks easy. The format is like below.

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET smtp_out_server = ''smtp.host.name''';
UTL_MAIL.send(sender => 'me@address.com',
        recipients => 'you@address.com',
           subject => 'Test Mail',
           message => 'Hello World',
         mime_type => 'text; charset=us-ascii');
END;
/
```

In my case,sender is not a fixed mail box. It can be like hostname@address.com. (I don't want to the same script for all the servers) Is there any way to invoke hostname when using UTL_MAIL function?

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: You can put this in a Procedure or Function, that has input parameters, like Sender, Recipients etc. and have this proc/func called differently - isn't that what you need ?

Answer (score 2):

You can find hostnames by making a SQL statement.

```
 select host_name into hostname from  v$instance
```